# Is it safe to modify the Android manifest file manually in an Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) environment?

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

I made some manual changes to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in an Apache Cordova project, using NetBeans IDE. It seems to work flawlessly.

Is it safe though? Will the manifest be overwritten by Cordova at some point? Will there be compatibility conflicts? Is this the intended way of configuring the Android application?

The changes would be necessary for features like a specific target SDK or App2SD for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldnt cause any problems. cordova may add a line or two if it uses anything special, but the manifest is not very fragile, and is meant to be manipulated. just dont mess with R.java!

i use mostly eclipse, but have used netbeans, and intellij as well as the android studio version of eclipse, and motodev as well... the only time ive had problems witha manifest was with unity, and that was user error(not watching what i typed)

SIDENOTE: in most cases you will manipulate the manifest in some way. adding admob (or other ad services) requires this, as well as adding any activities other than the default, however, if your not comfortable using the manifest i recomend using fragments, as fragment activities do not need to be declared in the manifest.